# Error on running Cron Command

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, crontab

I have connected my store with SSH terminal and then I navigated to the root directory of my store where I run the following command

```
*/5 * * * * cron.sh
```

But its showing this error: **bash: */5: No such file or directory**

Answer (score 1):

What you've written isn't a command that you can enter in the shell - it's a crontab entry that should go in a special file, which you can edit using crontab -e (user crontab) or sudo crontab -e (root crontab)

**View crontab**

To output/view the crontab of the current user

```
crontab -l
```

To view the crontab of another user you would need sudo permissions

```
sudo crontab -l -u nameOfOtherUser
```

**Edit crontab**

```
crontab -e
```

The possible cron line using full path to php

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/sitename/cron.php
```

or for **debugging** purposes

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php  -q /var/www/html/sitename/cron.php > /var/www/html/sitename/cron-error.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Cron.sh file is located in the root directory of my store and I navigated to the root directory of my store using SSH terminal, now which command I have to run?

Comment: in terminal check your root dir path for eg. pwd (present working directory) from ssh. what you get ?

Comment: It's showing the directory path /home/master/applications/tswguhztub/public_html

Comment: try entering `/home/master/applications/tswguhztub/public_html/cron.sh` and check

Comment: still the same result

Comment: are you trying to run the cron.sh file from the terminal ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59401/discussion-between-muneeb-syed-and-userpk).

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Take a break and restore any changes you've made to your cron.sh file and crontab. There is an easy and breezy way to setup Cron on your Magento store. I do this for every store I setup and it always work.

1. Disable Magento Compiler by running this code at your Magento root directory:

> ```
> php -f shell/compiler.php disable
> ```

2. Log into Admin Panel and disable all your cache:

> ```
> System > Cache Management > (Select All) > Actions: Disable > Submit
> ```

Then log out of Admin Panel.

3. Install AOE Scheduler from Magento Connect from this link: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html
4. After installation, run Magento compiler:

> ```
> php -f shell/compiler.php enable
>
> php -f shell/compiler.php compile
> ```

5. Log into Magento Admin Panel and re-enable all cache.
6. Then follow the instruction to set up Magento Cron:

> ```
> System > Scheduler > Instructions
> ```

Make sure you enable all recommended options.

7. After 5 minutes, Go to System > Scheduler > Timeline View to monitor your cron jobs.

If everything went well, you will see:

> Scheduler is working. (Last heart beat: x minute(s) ago)

Now Magento cron is functioning well. And all your newsletters, backups, transactional email jobs will execute according to the setting at:

> System > Scheduler > Job Configurations